# How to fetch Payload field value from Solr Query

Tags: solr

In My Solr Collection , I have field of type "Payload" and I wanted to see the value stored in specific document . Can you please suggest if there is any way to get the payload field value using Solr Query ?

I tried putting the field name in "fl" parameter list of Solr query but it does not return me Payload field in the result.

Please advice ?

Comment: Make sure you have updated the solrconfig.xml and the schema files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure field is stored. check in schema.xml file if Payload field is set `stored="true"`

```
<field name="Payload" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

if it is set to false, change it to true, restart solr and reindex you content. you see Payload field in your results.